# Version 5.0 is not allowed. Allowed version types are: majorVersion.x, majorVersion.minorVersion.x, majorVersion.minorVersion.patchVersion

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, .net-5

Recently we migrated a .NET Core 3.1 project to .NET 5.0.
We have few pipelines setup using AzureDevOps

On Modifying the version of .NET Core SDK task from 3.1.x to 5.0; we faced the below exception

> ##[error]Version 5.0 is not allowed. Allowed version types are: majorVersion.x, majorVersion.minorVersion.x,
> majorVersion.minorVersion.patchVersion. More details: The version
> number: 5.0 doesn't have the correct format. Versions can be given in
> the following formats: 2.x   => Install latest in major version. 2.2.x
> => Install latest in major and minor version. 2.2.104 => Install exact version. Find the value of `version` for installing SDK/Runtime, from
> the releases.json. The link to releases.json of that major.minor
> version can be found in [**releases-index
> file.**](https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/release-metadata/releases-index.json).
> Like link to releases.json for 2.2 version is
> https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/release-metadata/2.2/releases.json

Has AzureDevOps not been updated to .NET 5.0 or do we have to run test projects and pipelines only in .NET Core 3.1.x?

Also we are unable to locate any Agent job task available for .NET 5.0 in the Marketplace tab while creating the tasks.

Comment: Can you share your pipeline? You have an error message, but not the code that triggers the error? Based on the error, my suspect is you have a `5.0` version string when it expects `5.0.x` (extra `.x` needed).

Comment: It was resolved by the answer given below. Manual config on Yaml is best way to go. However agreed when I used 5.0.10 in version number and ignored global.json it worked as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use [UseDotNet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops) task to get the .NET 5.0 downloaded and used in subsequent dotnet build task. See below example:

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Install .Net 5 SDK'
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '5.0.100'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
```

Comment: It worked!!
Points to note 
1. task took more than 3 mins to complete. 
2. Separate tasks for UseDotNet, restore, test, build, publish and publish Artifact were used.

Still facing some restore issues though. Code exits with exit code 1. Something about Working directory not found.

Comment: @Aditya Glad to hear it worked. Could you accept above answer? since it worked. Thanks!  If you still experience some other issues, you can open new threads.

Comment: there is no UseDotNet task